# Ordering facets in a ggplot graph fails

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm experiencing behaviour in ggplot2 I cannot understand.

I am trying to sort facets in a graph according to values of the y-axes. This works if I try to order the facets according to the value of the y-axes at x = "0", however ordering according to the value of the y-axes at x = "4" does not give the desired result.

All help would be much appreciated!

Here's my data:

```
my_df <- structure(list(days_incubated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                  4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
                                  66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 116L, 
                                  116L, 116L, 116L), jar = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                             2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                             2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), co2 = c(15, 
                                                                                                                  5, 50, 30, 2, 89, 14.0, 
                                                                                                                  39.3, 1.2, 25.0, 10.27, 
                                                                                                                  29.5, 5.54, 38.13, 27.33, 
                                                                                                                  49.0, 28.62, 21.1, 24.0, 
                                                                                                                  0.6, 1.04, 7.94, 1.2, 
                                                                                                                  0.67, 1.9, 3.59, 4.92, 
                                                                                                                  0.02, 13.2, 20.3, 21.52, 
                                                                                                                  4.9, 6.6, 21.8, 12.28, 
                                                                                                                  2.9)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here's the code for the graph:

```
my_df %>%
  group_by(days_incubated)%>%
  mutate(co2_day0 = ifelse(days_incubated == 0, co2, NA),
         jar = fct_reorder(factor(jar),
                           co2_day0,
                           mean,
                           na.rm = TRUE,
                           .desc = FALSE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(days_incubated, co2)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean) +
  facet_wrap(vars(jar), scales = "free_y")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do all the calculations without breaking the pipe you could do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

n <- 0

my_df %>%
  mutate(jar = factor(jar, 
               jar[days_incubated == n][order(co2[days_incubated == n])])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(days_incubated, co2)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean) +
  facet_wrap(~jar, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

With `n = 4`

```
n <- 4
my_df %>%
  mutate(jar = factor(jar, 
                jar[days_incubated == n][order(co2[days_incubated == n])])) %>%
  ggplot(aes(days_incubated, co2)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean) +
  facet_wrap(~jar, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: So sorry I forgot to accept the answer, that was a clear mistake from my side!