# Ordering of facets in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking at the emission of acetone and acetaldehyde from different jars over time. My data set consists of four columns: `days_incubated jar compound emission`.

I wish to visualize the emission from each jar in facets. Each facet should show the emission from a jar over time, where acetone and acetaldehyde has different color and shape. The facets should be sorted according to the emission of acetaldehyde at days_incubated =0. E.g jars with higher emission of acetaldehyde at day 0 should be shown first in the graph

All help is much appreciated!

I have come up with this code, that takes me some of the way.

[![failed plot][1]][1]

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(days_incubated)%>%
  mutate(emission_rate_day0 = ifelse(days_incubated == 0, y = emission, NA),
         jar = fct_reorder(factor(jar),
                           emission_rate_day0,
                           mean,
                           na.rm = TRUE,
                           .desc = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=days_incubated, y=emission))+
  stat_summary(fun = mean) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=compound, color=compound)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "yellow")) + 
  labs(color = "Compound", shape = "Compound") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(jar), scales = "free_y")
```

and here's the data:

```
df <- structure(list(days_incubated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), jar = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), compound = c("Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", 
"Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", 
"Acetaldehyde", "Acetone", "Acetaldehyde"), emission = c(2.27, 
2.48, 0.15, 0.13, 7, 3.13, 0.33, 0.33, 6.26, 0.92, 0.11, 0.01, 
14.04, 10.38, 0.64, 0.98, 9.1, 0.32, 0.83, 0.02, 6.27, 0.51, 
0.77, 11.18)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2aUD.png
```

Comment: This answer didn't help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65139760/ordering-facets-in-a-ggplot-graph-fails

Comment: Yes it helped a lot, thanks again! The difference here is that I'm looking at two y-variables. For some reason there ends up being more dots in the plots than there should be.

Comment: Do you mean the two black dots in for each X variable - you don't want them both to be there?

Comment: Good that the other answer helped @Tiptop ! Is this now a separate problem to figure out? Do go and mark the other answer as 'accepted' if it's answered the question there and then this one can focus on what the new problem is.

Comment: Yes this is a separate question. I accepted the other answer now that worked perfectly for that issue. Sorry I forgot to accept it @Ronak Shah!

Comment: Yes @AndrewBaxter, the extra black dots are the problem

Comment: They are being added by the `stat_summary(fun = mean)` call. Your `geom_point()` adds a point for each row of your dataset (black and yellow for each compound) and `stat_summary()` is taking the mean of those two values for each grouping (by jar and days_incubated) and plotting a new point. It seems that you don't need this line if you don't want that extra pont?

Comment: (have put code and graph example below for clarity - do let me know if that helps or if it's been misunderstood)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Andrew, that fixed it!

Comment: Fab! I'll admit, it took me a while to get used to what the `stat_` layers were doing and how to work them out, so only just getting the hang of them recently. This helped https://yjunechoe.github.io/posts/2020-09-26-demystifying-stat-layers-ggplot2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the `stat_summary()` part, is this the graph you're trying to produce?:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

df %>%
  group_by(days_incubated)%>%
  mutate(emission_rate_day0 = ifelse(days_incubated == 0, y = emission, NA),
         jar = fct_reorder(factor(jar),
                           emission_rate_day0,
                           mean,
                           na.rm = TRUE,
                           .desc = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=days_incubated, y=emission))+
  geom_point(aes(shape=compound, color=compound)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "yellow")) + 
  labs(color = "Compound", shape = "Compound") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(vars(jar), scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>